# iOS アプリの質問 textview と　keyboard と　文字の関係について

Tags: swift

現在cell の中にtextview を置いて文字の量によってcellの大きさを変えているのですが、keyboardを使って文字を打っているときにtwitter のように打っている文字が見えるようにしたいのですが、キーボードの位置まで文字がくるとキーボードに隠れて見えなくなります。いろいろ調べたのですがわかりませんでした。教えていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

cellの大きさの最大値を固定することはできませんか？
例えば、UITextViewの高さのconstraintsを、「200以下」と設定するなどのように
cellの高さをどのように変更しているかに依りそうですが